# LAMP Whitescreen on Magento

Tags: php, apache, magento, lamp

First off, sorry if this shouldn't be on Stack Overflow, and instead should be on Server Fault / Super User.  I am pretty sure it is a programming issue...

I am getting a whitescreen on a Magento install for a PDF generation script.  I usually attribute whitescreens to memory issues on Apache, but:

- I am getting no visible errors (display_errors on and error reporint E_ALL)
- I am getting no errors in Apache's logs

The current memory for PHP is 256M which *should* be enough for an application like Magento.

I am a bit stuck now as to what is happening, and although have Zend Framework experience, don't want to go into the code too much at the moment to try and debug what is happening.

If anyone has any suggestions, it would be much appreciated.

I have command line access to the server.

Comment: Is error logging enabled? Take a look at `ErrorLog`.

Comment: Also, try a `phpinfo()` to see whether your settings were actually applied. It happens often that there are multiple php.inis on the system.

Comment: Checked phpinfo() and all looks in order.  Checking for ErrorLog - thanks for responses

Comment: No luck - I have forced other errors to test reporting and other errors are reported as expected.  Just can't catch the whitescreen problem.

Comment: I wonder if Magento has its own error handler? I don't have the codebase, so do a quick search for set_error_handler and see if you can tell if it's overriding the normal PHP error reporting...

Answer (score 1):

I would step through it using xdebug and netbeans personally.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you will have to go old skool, using the following code:

```
echo 'hi';
exit();
```

move it down line by line, until you get the white screen again, then you can narrow down the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit of a long winded way of trying to find the error, and in Zend Framework that will take a while, but at the moment I may have to do it!